# Using OOP to make Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am new to programming so I've taken a simple online project and tried to use OOP to make the GUI for it, can you help me with this error:

```
'RuntimeError: Too early to run the main loop: no default root window'
```

I took out the buttons to make it shorter:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

contact_list = [
    ['Dermot Bruce', '071 0403 6313'],
    ['Felix Kent', '071 7050 4862'],
    ['Eren Yeager', '071 4174 1560'],
    ['Roy Mustang'  '071 5173 4259'],
    ['Arietta Curtis', '071 4415 8004'],
    ['Jennifer Love', '071 8857 1196'],
]


class address_list():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.contact = contact_list


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, address_list)
        self.title = "Address Book Interface"
        self.geometry('400x400')
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.config(bg='lightblue')

        self.name = StringVar()
        self.number = StringVar()
        # create frame
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(side=RIGHT)

        def add_contact(contact_list):
            contact_list.append([self.name.get(), self.number.get()])
            select_set()

        # to view selected contact(first select then click on view button

        def edit(contact_list):
            contact_list[Selected()] = [self.name.get(), self.number.get()]
            select_set()

        def view(contact_list):
            NAME, PHONE = contact_list[Selected()]
            self.name.set(NAME)
            self.number.set(PHONE)

        # to delete selected contact

        def delete(contact_list):
            del contact_list[Selected()]
            select_set()

        # empty name and number field

        def reset(contact_list):
            self.name.set('')
            self.number.set('')

        # exit game window

        def exit(contact_list):
            self.destroy()

        def select_set(contact_list):
            contact_list.sort()
            select.delete(0, END)
            for name, phone in contact_list:
                enter
                code
                hereselect.insert(END, self.name)

        select_set()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainloop()
```

Comment: To initialize tkinter you have to add a root (default) window. you can add it using `root=Tk()`

Comment: @NishaniKasineshan no, they are inheriting from `Tk` so simply use `.mainloop()` on the instance

Comment: even within classes? I thought that was handled as tk.Tk__init__(self) will that fix the runtime error?

Comment: instead of `mainloop()` use `App().mainloop()`, also yes obviously you need to first call the class, it won't do anything just by being defined

Comment: and don't use `*` when importing

Comment: I tried App().mainloop() at the end and I got the same error, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean

Comment: can you show exactly how you tried it? [edit] question

Answer (score 1):

This error means exactly what it says. You can’t call `mainloop` until you’ve created a root window, and you never create any widgets.

Your code should look like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: there is also an issue with this line: `tk.Tk.__init__(self, address_list)`, sth about `create()` argument because `address_list` is a type

Comment: @Matiiss, yes, but that is unrelated to this error.

Comment: I currently have quite a few errors, with;               app = App()        &                                   tk.Tk.__init__(self, address_list)